# Per Diem Rates - CSV file download (data.gov)

Tags: data.gov

I have a couple of questions related to the Per Diem Rates information that inventory.data.gov provides.

1. We have been downloading your **Per Diem rates CSV file** from the following links in the recent past, but the link now (I have been trying since yesterday) gives me a "404 Not Found".

This was the link we have been using in the past:
https://inventory.data.gov/dataset/ad729937-b245-4eec-a88d-b72eb36d8106/resource/8ea44bc4-22ba-4386-b84c-1494ab28964b/download/perdiemreimbursementrates.csv

Is there another/changed link for the older CSV version?

I am aware of the other page/link which gives an Xls file:
***https://www.gsa.gov/travel/plan-book/per-diem-rates/per-diem-files***
but the data layout is completely different, and more so it doesn't give Zip Code-related information. On the other hand, the CSV Version gives the information in the way it can be used for what is needed. It is just not the data formats (CSV v/s Xls) that are the issue for us, but the data content as a whole that is an issue with the Xls file.

2. We have also been using the **Per Diem API** to get rates. This is the link we have been using:
   https://inventory.data.gov/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=8ea44bc4-22ba-4386-b84c-1494ab28964b&limit=300000&filters=%7B%22FiscalYear%22:%222019%22,%22Zip%22:%2292692%22%7D

This API has been having some issues since the last couple of days that we have been monitoring it:
***"Access denied: User  not authorized to read resource 8ea44bc4-22ba-4386-b84c-1494ab28964b", "__type": "Authorization Error"***

And today it has been giving an "Internal Server Error" off and on.

We are aware that GSA is now offering a new API for the Per Diem rates.
https://open.gsa.gov/api/perdiem/

We would like to know if the older API (from inventory.data.gov) will continue to be offered for Customers who would like to use it.

Can you please help or guide me to some contact at inventory.data.gov who can answer the related questions?

Comment: Please explain *don't find it any more*. Do you mean that the data is only available in *other* formats (specifically, XLS - in which case juist download, read into Excel and export as csv yourself). You also write *Following link will download the newest csv*, but that link is dead. Please [edit] your question. What is your question exactly?

Comment: From the [data.gov] tag, I think that you may have come from a goverment website, but you are now on a worldwide forum on Open Data. So writing *Your data* does not apply, you are not addressing a US goverment agency. Yes, I know, confusing. We have [several agencies doing this](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351/editing-a-tags-name-wondering-about-us-gov-involvement-just-the-usual)

Comment: data.gov is on github, where you'll probably have much more luck getting an answer from them. its also no surprise this eventually 404'd; data.gov is where links go to die, aka linkrot heaven.